# a xmlhttprequest.send() crash in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-states

I was trying to learn XmlHttpRequest. I followed [this W3School Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp).

in the file httprequest.0.js:

```
function myHttpRequestFunction()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

alert("A"); 
xmlhttp.open("GET","httprequest.0.xml",false);
alert("B"); 
xmlhttp.send(); // never succeeds this line !
alert("C");
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
alert("D");
```

}

Everything seems to break at that line: `xmlhttp.send();`

are there exception catchers in Javascript or anything so as to manage such crash ? maybe xmlhttprequest states ?

in the file httprequest.0.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="httprequest.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myHttpRequestFunction()">
    <h3>XMLHttpRequest</h3><p>
    <div id="RequestContent"> </div>    
</body>
</html>`
```

in the file httprequest.0.xml:

```
<root>Test Httprequest.0</root>
```

Do you have any advice ?

Comment: Best suggestion:  Forget w3schools and get [mootools](http://mootools.net/).

Comment: @DrStrangeLove... mhh what do you mean ?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem.  What browser are you testing this on?

Comment: I use Chrome, lattest version.

Comment: As you use chrome you may also wish to install the blocklist extension, which you can use to filter out low quality sites such as w3schools.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef

Comment: @leeeb okay, but it would be very nice to know simply why this code is wrong !? ( I installed the extension thx :-) )

Answer (score 1):

try sending this:

```
xmlhttp.send(null);
```